# Julia merging dataframes

Tags: dataframe, merge, julia

i am rather new to julia so apologies if this is a rather trivial question. However I have stumbled upon a problem i cannot resolve so appreciate any help/suggestions.

I have a function which returns a set of values in a dataframe when I run it. Something along the lines of:

`(values) = function(data)`

However I run this function in

[for example see here][1]

I run this function in a loop so that each time it runs, I get a new set of values.

```
for x = 1:5
    (values) = function(data[data[:sub].==[x], :])
end
```

After the function runs, I then want to put the values that come back into a "master" data frame which has exactly the same column headings and compiles the values that come back on each loop iteration.

This seems infuriatingly tricky to do. I tried using `append!` as described here:

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/adding-a-new-row-to-a-dataframe/1331/3

But this does not work. For example if I run the following commands

```
(values_1) = function(data[data[:sub].==[1], :])

(values_2) = function(data[data[:sub].==[2], :])

append(values_1, values_2)
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
MethodError: no method matching append!(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,2})
Closest candidates are:
  append!(::PyCall.PyObject, ::Any) at /Users/neil/.julia/v0.5/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:836
  append!(::Array{T,1}, ::Any) at collections.jl:21
  append!{T}(::PyCall.PyVector{T}, ::Any) at /Users/neil/.julia/v0.5/PyCall/src/conversions.jl:278

 in append!(::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::DataFrames.DataFrame) at /Users/neil/.julia/v0.5/DataFrames/src/dataframe/dataframe.jl:791
 in include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:441
 in include_string(::String, ::String) at /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?
```

Note that the function does correctly return a dataframe each time I run it, it is just the concatanation of values that is causing problems.

appreciate any pointers.
n

Comment: FYI, no need for parens on the left side of equals, eg `values = f()` works and is more commonly used than `(values) = f()`.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `vcat`, e.g. `vcat(values_1, values_2)`. There might be a better way to do what you're doing, though, but it's hard to give specific advice without an 'MWE', i.e. an example we can paste into a terminal, run and rewrite.

Comment: If you save your partial DataFrames in an Array, you can use `masterDf = vcat(myArray...)`

Comment: Exactly, I was going to comment that if the OP cared enough about his question to respond to my answer.

Comment: [OT] Sometimes when I make a question I don't know if replying to an answer that satisfy me or not (other than approve/vote it up).. On one side, I am tempted to say "thank you", but on the other one I think I may bother the user with such an uninformative "comment"..

Comment: I think you're not supposed to answer, but just mark it as answered. But in this case I asked for an MWE because there are lots of tools like the one you suggested to do what the OP seems to want in a smoother way.